Smooth function interpolating a triangle and a point at specific values.
Imagine that in the real plane you have a segment $[p_1, p_2]$ and a point not on that segment $q$.
Is there a function $f(X): \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that:

$f$ is smooth
$f(p_1) = f(p_2) = \frac{1}{2}$
$f(q) = 0$
$f((p_1 + p_2)  \frac{1}{2}) = 1$

?

There are plenty of such options, many of which involve linear combinations of some set of radial basis functions. Depending on what kind of smoothness you want (and whether there are any properties of the interpolation you haven't listed), you could for example choose a set of four Gaussian functions of the form $\varphi_i(r) = \exp(-\varepsilon_i^2 r^2)$ and then fit
$$f(\mathbf{x}) = w_1 \varphi_1(||\mathbf{x} - p_1||) + w_2 \varphi_2(||\mathbf{x} - p_2||) + w_3 \varphi_3(||\mathbf{x} - q||) + w_4 \varphi_4(||\mathbf{x} - \frac{1}{2}(p_1 + p_2)||$$
by choosing the weights so that it hits the right values at the chosen points.
